# How to remove a character from the values of a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, list, dictionary, strip

dict_data =  {'c': ['d\n', 'e\n'], 'm':['r\n','z\n','o']}
a dictionary dict_data remove '\n' in the values 
(order is not important.):

should return: {'c': ['d', 'e'], 'm':['r','z','o']}
This is what I tried:

```
def dicts(dict_data):
    for k, v in dict_data.items():
        for i in v:
            f = i.strip('\n')
return f
```

How can i get this without doing anything to complicated?

Comment: Do it when you're building the dictionary, instead of modifying it after it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right approach but you've probably assumed that altering `i` with `i.strip('\n')` in `for i in v` might make the change appear in `dict_data`. This isn't the case. What you're doing is altering `i` and then discarding the result.

A correct approach would be to build a list of the stripped elements and re-assign to the corresponding dictionary key:

```
def strip_dicts(dict_data):
    for k, v in dict_data.items():
        f = []
        for i in v:
             f.append(i.strip('\n'))
        dict_data[k] = f
```

of course, remember, this alters the argument dictionary *in-place*.

You can create a different function that returns a new dictionary by using a comprehension:

```
def strip_dicts(d):
    return {k: [i.strip() for i in v] for k,v in d.items()}
```